# Fourier transform of white noise - Phase and magnitude?

Tags: variance, fourier-transform

Assume that $X(t)$ describes white noise in time, with $\langle X(t) \rangle =0 $ and $\langle X(t) X(t') \rangle = \sigma^2 \delta(x-x')$. I want to know the distribution of it's Fourier transform. The latter is defined as

$$X(\omega) =\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt  e^{i \omega t} X(t)$$

In particular, I am interested in the distributions of the phase and the magnitude.

Since no phase is special, I would intuitively assume, that the phase has a uniform distrubition in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. But what about the magnitude?